# How to fetch data in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, fetch, vuejs3

I don't know how to fetch data with Vue 3? I created one action and with this action I am calling endpoint (https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries/5494). I didn't get response data.

Endpoint:

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
    async getData() {
      await fetch('https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries/5494', {
        method: 'get',
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
      }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        console.log('response: ', response)
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
      });
    }
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

Vue component:

```html
<template>
  <div @click="loadData">Load Data</div>
</template>

<script>
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },

  setup () {
    const store = useStore()

    const loadData = () => {
      store.dispatch('getData')
    }

    return { loadData }
  }
}
</script>
```

As a response I didn't get anything but I should get:

```
{"id":5494,"name":"MadTree Brewing","brewery_type":"regional","street":"3301 Madison Rd","address_2":null,"address_3":null,"city":"Cincinnati","state":"Ohio","county_province":null,"postal_code":"45209-1132","country":"United States","longitude":"-84.4239715","latitude":"39.1563725","phone":"5138368733","website_url":"http://www.madtreebrewing.com","updated_at":"2018-08-24T15:44:22.281Z","created_at":"2018-07-24T01:34:01.620Z"}
```

Comment: whats `actions: {`? vuex, if so where are you calling it?

Comment: As Lawrence said, where is the action being executed? Then you have to call a mutation with the response that fills your store. An action cannot mutate a store variable. If you use this in the component just make a method out of it

Comment: @wittgenstein

You can find test project as a example, just install nod modules and run, and you will see what I mean. 
Test project: [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a067b85a774f5fba14be8e1e5b58224a20210314181054/f860ff)
If you click on Load data div, you can see response in console, but not response data like above.

Comment: No, thanks - I won't download anything.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I added Vue component where I am calling action.

Comment: remove the `await`. and it will work

Comment: @AdarshMohan 
Still doesn't work.

Comment: CORS error doesn't mean the API calls are not working. which means the domain from which you are invoking the API is blocked from the domain in which the API is available.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the data to json

```
.then(res=>res.json())
```

this will do the trick for you.

```js
const getData = () => {
  fetch('https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries/5494', {
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
  }).then(res=>res.json()).then((response) => {
    console.log({ response })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
  });
}

getData();
```

If the response fails, it will surely get you to catch.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. Now I created wamp/www/api/test.php and in that file I'm just doing echo 'test' and instead of response, I got "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0".

Comment: And Status Code: 304 Not Modified

Comment: @kasp3rsky its because the response from the url is not a json

Comment: It should be, actually I do echo json_encode('test').

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66628483/2827397) Should be the accepted answer.

If readers landed here while working through the [introductory examples on the Vue.js website](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#what-is-vue-js), Adarsh's code can be adapted thusly (for Vue.js 3):

```js
<div id="beer">
  {{ message }}
</div>

const Breweries = {
    data() {
        return {
            message: ""
        }},
    mounted() {
        fetch('https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries/', {
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
        }).then(res=>res.json()).then((response) => {
            this.message = response;
        }).catch( (error) => {
            this.message = error;
        });
    }
}
Vue.createApp(Breweries).mount('#beer')
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must install a package like axios
Then create an object from axios and call the API

```
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  setup() {
    function getUsers() {
      axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .then(function (response) {
          // handle success
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // handle error
          console.log(error);
        });
      getUsers();
    }
    return { getUsers };
  },
};
```