# Issue with CORS during Rest call between Vue3 Web app and C# .NET CORE Web API Localhost testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, vuejs3, asp.net-core-webapi

I have built out an extremely simple 'hello world' equivalent bit of Web API code to make sure my connections work.

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("BaseTest")]
public async Task<string> BaseTest()
{
    return "TESTING";
}
```

And this bit of Vue 3 front-end to fetch from that API

```js
fetch('https://localhost:7209/MapData/BaseTest', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "x-access-token": "token-value",
    },
    crossorigin: true,
    mode: 'no-cors',
}).then(response => alert(response));
```

The response is an object Response. Status of *null*, ok of false, and type of opaque.

When I execute the same post call in postman, I receive the string, "TESTING" as expected.

**What should I check for and/or what is my mistake?**

I was hoping for a very simple, extremely accomplishable, "Hello World" equivalent, receiving "TESTING" on the Vue 3 app.  Instead, it's failing miserably.

I have tried accessing the response data via:

- `response.text()`
- `response.json()`
- a number of other member variables beneath response; some which were just hopeful thinking.

I have verified that the response is coming back:

- `ok = false`
- `type = opaque`
- `status = ''`
- `statusText = ''`

I have tried catching any errors that may be thrown, and received none.

I have tried adjusting the Web API to be synchronous or return ActionResults, and neither work.

I have verified that the swagger testing page and postman are both capable of receiving a simple "TESTING" response when making a POST call to this URL.

---

Edit 1:
I have adjusted my code to try the following:

C# endpoint *Attempt #1*:

```
...
        [EnableCors("LocalHostOrigins")]        
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("BaseTest")]
        public async Task<String> BaseTest()
        {
            return "TESTING";
        }
...
```

C# Program.cs *Attempt #1*:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: LocalHostOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5173", "http://localhost:*");
        });
    options.AddPolicy(name: AllOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("*");
        });
});
...
app.UseCors();
```

C# endpoint *Attempt #2*:

```
        [EnableCors]        
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("BaseTest")]
        public async Task<String> BaseTest()
        {
            return "TESTING";
        }
```

C# Program.cs *Attempt #2*:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("*:*");
    });
});
...

app.UseCors();
```

C# endpoint *Attempt #3*:

```
        [EnableCors]        
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("BaseTest")]
        public async Task<String> BaseTest()
        {
            return "TESTING";
        }
```

C# Program.cs *Attempt #3*:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => {});
...
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();
});
...
```

Vue3 web app, in all scenarios:

```
...
        fetch('https://localhost:7209/MapData/BaseTest')
            .then(response => alert(response)); // [object Response]
        fetch('https://localhost:7209/MapData/BaseTest')
            .then(response => alert(response.text())); // [object Promise]
        fetch('https://localhost:7209/MapData/BaseTest')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => alert(data)); // empty string
...
```

My current concern is that, even in scenarios where it appears CORS is functioning as expected and desired, my request is still coming through with null data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch data in Vue 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66625010/how-to-fetch-data-in-vue-3)

Comment: [how can i fetch a normal String to the data in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70790085/how-can-i-fetch-a-normal-string-to-the-data-in-vue)

Comment: This is actually an issue with CORS, as it almost always is when the request works in postman but not in browser... see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268722)

Comment: @Ibram Reda yes.  That did not work.  It returned undefined.

Comment: @yoduh - I am in the middle of giving your route a serious look-through.  I assumed CORS shouldn't even be necessary right now, as this is *all* localhost based.  But that didn't work, either.

Comment: You must enable cores in asp to allow different cores communication as mentioned by @yoduh see [How to enable CORS in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: You should keep your eyes on the console output, you will find useful errors messages related to the problem

Comment: @Ibram Reda - The console returns nothing when I get the response back that I have written.  The response type is opaque, which I've read tends to carry little to no information.  
I may close and re-open this question, as I have gone through learning how to enable CORS, establish policies, allow endpoints (specifically the localhost and port my web front-end uses, as well as trying a broad-stroke "*") and both response.data() and response.json() return an [object Response] with null data, in every case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using below code for testing, and not facing the same issue.

If I comment `app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");`, my page should have cors issue like below. Using `catch` could capture the error.

[image]

**Success Pic**

[image]

[image]

**Full Code**

**TestAPI.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="testApi">Test API</button>
    <p v-if="apiResponse">{{ apiResponse }}</p>
    <p v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      apiResponse: null,
      error: null, 
    };
  },
  methods: {
    testApi() {
      fetch('https://localhost:7180/BaseTest', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "x-access-token": "token-value",
        },
      })
      .then(response => {
       
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response is not ok');
        }
        return response.text();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.apiResponse = data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('API Invoke Error:', error);
        this.error = error.stack; 
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Program.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            // allow all Origin
            builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials();
            }));

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            // add this line
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure of ALL the elements to take into consideration that got this to function for me, but I can point out two of them:

1. At some point, I had removed the "method: POST" from my request in Vue.js, which was necessary for my endpoint.

2. return response.text(), .then(data => alert(data)) works, whereas simply attempting alert(response.text()) does not; it would always return an [object Promise], as I had been receiving, earlier.

At this point, this post is exactly where it deserves to be; I doubt it will help anyone, but it's a small laundry list of things-to-check!